# Build linked list with the predicated function in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have this assignature `typedef int (*FuncaoPredicado)(void *)` and the function receives a `void *` parameter and returns integer value that if is nonzero, the parameter has the desired predicate, otherwise, it returns zero value.

I created a generic function to build a linked list with numbers divisible by 3 from the original list.

```
int predicadoDivisivelPor3(void *info) {
  int *pi = (int *)info;
  return (*pi % 3) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The `split` function implementation

```
pDLista split(pDLista pd, FuncaoPredicado fp, FuncaoImpressao pfi) {
  pDLista pNovaListaComPredicado = criarLista();
  pNoh atual = pd->primeiro;

  while(atual != NULL) {
    if(fp(atual->info) == 1) {
      pNovaListaComPredicado->primeiro = atual->prox;
      pNovaListaComPredicado->ultimo = pd->ultimo;
      pNovaListaComPredicado->quantidade = pd->quantidade;

      pd->ultimo = atual;
      atual->prox = NULL;
    }
    atual = atual->prox;
  }

  printf("\n");  

  return pNovaListaComPredicado;
}
```

The function `FuncaoPredicado fp` is an argument that I will receive in `main.c` with my function `predicadoDivisivelPor3`.
`split(pListaInt, predicadoDivisivelPor3, imprimeInt);`

When I call at the `main.c`

```
pDLista divisao = split(pListaInt, predicadoDivisivelPor3, imprimeInt);
imprimirLista(divisao, imprimeInt);
```

The linked list I created is `1 - 3 - 5 - 6 - 9 -`  but the result about this split function is `5 - 6 - 9`.

But now I'm not able to implement to create a new list with the predicate.

Comment: The code is awful. The question is unclear.

Comment: By "new list", do you mean you want to remove those nodes from the original list and insert them into the other?  Or do you want to _copy_ them into a new list without modifying the original list?  If you want to remove them, you'll just need to remember the previous node as you traverse so that you can modify the linkage.  Unless it's a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Ok I will edit @VladfromMoscow and put more information.

Comment: @paddy I want to copy to another list.

Comment: Okay, so you already know how to build a list because you've done it already.  So just do that when the predicate matches, copying the value from the other list onto the new node in the new list.  We can't really advise more than that.  You haven't shown your code that can allocate and build a list, and you haven't explained why you're "not able" to implement this.

Comment: @paddy I implemented and edited the post about `split` function but my result was `5 - 6 - 9` using the original list `1 - 3 - 5 - 6 - 9`

Comment: You're just modifying pointers of the new list to point into the other list.  That's asking for trouble.  If you want to _copy_ a list then you need to allocate memory for new nodes and link them within that _new_ list.  Do not point from one list into another list unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @paddy I got! I will comment the correct.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Could you remove the unvote post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish the `split` implementation I saw about another function that I have the `duplicarLista` that makes the same implementation but I just needed to add a validation about the predicated function.

```
pDLista split(pDLista pd, FuncaoPredicado fp, FuncaoImpressao pfi, FuncaoAlocacao fa) {
  pDLista pNovaListaComPredicado = criarLista();
  pNoh atual = pd->primeiro;

  pNovaListaComPredicado->primeiro = NULL;
  pNovaListaComPredicado->ultimo = NULL;
  pNovaListaComPredicado->quantidade = 0;

  while(atual != NULL) {
    if(fp(atual->info) == 1) {
      void *auxInfo = fa(atual->info);
      incluirInfo(pNovaListaComPredicado, auxInfo);
    }
    atual = atual->prox;
  }

  printf("\n");  

  return pNovaListaComPredicado;
}
```